# Transpose function, decimal to binary

Tags: c, binary

i am trying to develop a transpose function which can transpose from decimal to binary an up to 9digits number. I'm pretty new on coding and this is my first try. But it does not seem to be working, sorry if i am asking something obvious, but i need some help. Thanks in advance.

```
void transpose(int n)

{
int c, k;
for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
{
k = (n % c);


if (k == 0) printf("1");
else printf("0");
}
}
```

Comment: you don't update `n`, it should be `n = n / 2`, btw your should print in reverse.

Comment: That's not transposition, nor is the input decimal. That's printing a number in binary.

Comment: Hint: Bit 31 being set doesn't mean that the number is divisible by 31. You should probably read some more about binary representation and the bitwise operators.

Comment: Suggest using `unsigned n` to avoid unexpected effects using negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using arithmetic operations, you could use bitwise operations and get the digit directly:

```
for (c = 31; c >= 0; --c)
{
    printf("%d", (n >> c) & 1);
}
```

This shifts the value in `n` right by `c` steps, i.e. putting bit number `c` in the rightmost (least-signigficant) bit. Then the mask with `1` will result in either a one or a zero, which is then printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void transpose(int n){
    unsigned x;
    char bits[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n)+1];
    char *p = bits +  CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n);
    *p = '\0';
    for(x=n; p!=bits ;x>>=1)
        *--p = "01"[x & 1];
    puts(bits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging your program for `n = 5`:
When `c` becomes `5`, `1` get printed after 26 `0`'s

```
000000000000000000000000001
```

now for rest of `c` (till `0`), the output is

```
00000000000000000000000000100000
```

and unfortunately this is not `5` in decimal. Hope you understand what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether a number n is divisible by all numbers 31 to 0. This is not what you need to do to convert the base.
Where a decimal representation shows you a number, for instance, 6174 (kapreka constant)
as  able to be built up out of these blocks:

4 * 10^0

7 * 10^1

1 * 10^3

6 * 10^4

0*..

0*..

you would want your transpose function to result in a representation of powers of 2. I hope this helps directing you to an answer.